# Call all methods within a class

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class, which has a method calls all of the rest methods within the same class.

One way to do it is by using reflection framework, are there other ways?

[edit]
Example code added:

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;


public class AClass {

    private void aMethod(){

    }

    private void bMethod(){

    }

    private void cMethod(){

    }

    private void dMethod(){

    }

    //50 more methods. 

    //method call the rest
    public void callAll() throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException{
        Method[] methods = this.getClass().getMethods();
        for (Method m : methods) {
            if (m.getName().endsWith("Method")) {
                //do stuff..
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I actually don't have a problem with calling all 4 methods from callAll(), i.e. avoid using reflection. But one of my colleagues pointed out that what if there are 50 methods, are you going to call them one by one? I don't have an answer for that, that's why I am asking the question here.

Thanks,
Sarah

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Could you show some code? Because I have trouble understanding what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @finnw, I've updated my question. Actually I'm trying to prove your point "Why would you want to do that" to a colleague, that's why I am asking the question here.

Comment: @Sarah, why didn't your coworker point out that, "... why are you doing this?" - I think that's a much more interesting question.

Comment: @Slomojo, I was actually asking him "why are you doing this?" But he said that "what if there are 50 methods? Are you going to type all of them? ". I can say to him "no good, you are only doing this for convenience ", but he would say "why not?". Then how should I answer?

Comment: @All, maybe I should change my question to "why don't you want to do that"? Is it more interesting now?

Comment: @Sarah, yes, I think it's more interesting to understand why someone would want to do this, it seems like the class structure is being abused, for example, a better way to implement this list of calls is using a set of command classes, (implementing an ICommand interface, which requires an execute method, and then just pushing them through a loop.) If you have a class that has 50 methods and they are all supposed to be run by another method in the same class, it is a textbook example of breaking the single responsibility principle.

Comment: @Sarah, I'm sure a more fitting title will present itself to you as we all begin to understand the issue being faced. For now it seems like "Why would someone want to call all the methods in a class, from the same class?" ... would be useful in attracting more answers.

Comment: @Slomojo, thanks for pointing out that the actual problem is that "why would you want to call all the methods from the same class". I finally understood why you guys are asking "Why would you want to do that"!

Comment: Although reflection will work, this is the perfect time to take a step back and redesign your class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that anything you end up doing is going to ultimately boil down to reflection anyways; eg: aspects, DI, etc. So I don't know what the gain would be - convenience maybe?

Comment: Hey, can you please give some info or links about aspects and DI?

Comment: Forget it, it's not relevant here (but try Wiki or Google, DI = dependency injection here). Reflection is the way how methods can be enumerated. You could analyze the class-file instead using e.g., cglib, but I don't thing it'd be any better. As everybody else, I'm asking "why do you want it"?

Comment: @Greenhorn, relevant or not [here you go](http://java.dzone.com/articles/dependency-injection-an-introd).

Answer (score 6):

Actually, you'd probably want to use [`Class.getDeclaredMethods()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods%28%29). [`Class.getMethods()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethods%28%29) only returns public methods and none of the methods you show are public (and it also returns the public methods inherited from super classes).

That said: In the scenario you mention, reflection is a valid approach. All other (manual) approaches would be error-prone.

However, using a naming convention seems to weak to me as a guard. I'd write a custom annotation, and if that is present, I'd execute the method. Example:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface RunMe {}
```

And here's your modified code:

```
public void callAll() throws
IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException{
    Method[] methods = this.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
    for (Method m : methods) {
        if (m.getAnnotation(RunMe.class)!=null) {
            //do stuff..
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Write the `callAll()` method to actually call each method explicitly without reflection.**

This allows for flexibility in subclassing.  It also allows you to deal with methods which have parameters.  It also allows you to bypass methods which don't apply.  Most importantly, it makes it really easy to change your code when requirements change and this blanket rule no longer applies.

"Calling all methods on a class" is just not a valid use-case.  I've seen JUnit call all methods without arguments beginning with "test" to do test cases.  That's about the closest I've come, and if your goal is to do something like this, then you are on the right track.  If you were working on something like this, though, I don't think you'd be looking for alternatives to reflection.

Comment: Junit4 uses java.lang.reflect.Method.getAnnotation(Class<? extends Annotation>) != null to filter @Test methods, so it's also reflect.

Answer (score 0):

I just thought for some reason I'd quickly write the Java way of approaching this problem. Obviously it's verbose and OOP based.

Because we can't use pointers to methods in Java, we have to make Objects that have methods and then call them. You could always change the method even to take arbitrary amounts of arbitrary arguments etc.

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;


public class AClass {

  private List<Method> methods = new LinkedList<>();

  methods.push( new Method()
  {
    private void callMethod(){
      //method A
    }
  });

  methods.push( new Method()
  {
    private void callMethod(){
      //method B
    }
  });

  methods.push( new Method()
  {
    private void callMethod(){
      //method C
    }
  });

  //50 more methods. 

  //method call the rest
  public void callAll()
  {
     for (Method method : methods) {
        method.callMethod();
     }
  }
}

public interface Method
{
  void callMethod();
}
```